# Animated Div Panel

Tags: jquery, css, html

Hi Guys I'm looking for div panel which has this animation when mouse is over panel will expand and in the background page will get an opacity. http://www.emirates.com/uk/english/index.aspx here is an example what I'm trying to mean if you go down to 4 pics on the bottom of the page you will understand what I mean..

Thanks in advance

Comment: They're using jQuery UI to implement this animation.

Comment: when you already know that your linked page has the functionality you are looking for, why don't you just go through the code of the page and track how it works?

Comment: I know but what I'm asking is that what is that animation I tried mouseover div expand but its not the same, do you know any examples similar to that I need to use it.. if i knew exactly what sort of jquery they used i would go through every code figure it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a similar solution:

html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<img id="smallBall" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Button_Icon_BlueSky.svg/300px-Button_Icon_BlueSky.svg.png" />
<img id="animateBall" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Button_Icon_BlueSky.svg/300px-Button_Icon_BlueSky.svg.png" />
```

javascript:

```
$('#smallBall ').mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: "0.3",
        filter: "alpha(opacity=30)"
    }, 500);
    $('#animateBall ').animate({
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        left: "+=25",
        top: "+=25"
    }, 500);
});$('#smallBall ').mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: "1.0",
        filter: "alpha(opacity=100)"
    }, 500);
    $('#animateBall ').animate({
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
        left: "-=25",
        top: "-=25"
    }, 500);
});
```

Try it [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/cXZTs/3/)

BTW: I through this together really quickly so I didn't work on the problems causing the false positives on the mouseLeave events. A more clearly defined boundary on the target would fix this problem I imagine.

You could also toggle it onClick  [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/A8gLd/)

Comment: Thanks James i will try to implement but it doesn't seems the right one anyways will try :)

Comment: Your welcome.. Sorry if I misunderstood the question. Hope it works for you.

Comment: James what's this animation called in general maybe i can work around it..

Comment: If I understand the question, the opacity animation can be created by using the .fadeTo() function. This is probably actually a better solution than I gave because the jquery lib would keep up with future browser specs.

Comment: The real question is I want to create divs just like the ones on there, I mean when I hover my mouse on it my div will expand in an animated way opacity isn't a problem..

Comment: Oh.. Try [This](http://jsfiddle.net/cXZTs/12/). Not sure on browser support.

Comment: Or [This](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz3hx/).

Comment: Thank you James that did the trick much appriciated :)